# Sort pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, pointer-to-pointer

I'm trying to sort an array of strings that is implemented using a pointer to a pointer. The code I am using is:

```
void sort(){
  char** names;
  for(int i = 1; i < size; i++){
    int k = i;
    while((strcmp(names[k],names[k-1]) < 0) && (k > 0)){
      char* temp;
      temp = names[k];
      names[k] = names[k-1];
      names[k-1] = temp;
      k--;
    }
  }
}
```

names is already initialized and filled with 7 names in another method. I get a seg fault at this line

```
 names[k] = names[k-1];
 names[k-1] = temp;
```

but I'm not sure why exactly. I get the seg fault after the first iteration of the while loop, and k is decremented to 0. It never returns to the for loop to increment i and k again. Can someone explain why I am getting the seg fault and how to fix it?

Comment: `names` can't be initialised in another method, since it's locally defined in the one you're showing?

Comment: I only did that to show that names is a char**. Its not actually declared there

Comment: @tcas271 We have no idea *how* your `char**` was initialized or set up.  That in itself could be one cause of the crash.

Comment: @tcas271 Don't post bogus code here, we require a [MCVE] actually!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(strcmp(names[k],names[k-1]) < 0) && (k > 0)` is wrong.  The correct form is
 `(k > 0) && (strcmp(names[k],names[k-1]) < 0)`

The sequence matters because `names[k-1]` is unsafe to read when `k` is zero.  `&&` always computes its left operand first and only computes its right operand when the left is `true`